# How do connect mysql to Angular and display data in html

Tags: mysql, angular, electron

i am new to Angular. i have added electron with the angular together. Is there a way to connect an existing mysql database or create my own and display of the data into the app.component.html?

Comment: Is `mysql` installed on your server?

Comment: There needs to be some sort of exposed Service or API you build that you angular app calls that would fetch that data from your database. If you search on "add an api to mysql", you will find some of the many ways to do that.

Comment: @TheHeadRush yes i have.

Comment: @Mathias is it using some webapi/restful api?

Comment: Yes, you call the API to get (and possibly change) your data